# FunctionsStartup not being called after installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook, causing DI failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using the latest Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.7.
After installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook FunctionsStartup doesn't execute causing DI failure. Not sure if this is related to the sdk update or the fb nuget, but if I uninstall the fb nuget FunctionsStartup works fine again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is getting this error, here is a possible solution:

[Azure Functions: host error has occurred during startup operation Could not load file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434453/azure-functions-host-error-has-occurred-during-startup-operation-could-not-load)