# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

In my azure function app project, I receive an assembly not found runtime error Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0. However, the assembly is included in multiple packages I installed from NuGet.

Visual Studio: 2019
Target Framework: netcoreapp3.1
Azure Functions Version: v3

Installed packages containing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (5.0.0):

- Microsoft.Extensions.Http (5.0.0)
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (5.0.0)
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource (5.0.0)

***Error:***
A host error has occurred during startup operation...
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

***Ineffective fix attempts:***
Installed Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (5.0.0) from NuGet, but error persists.

Following a similar issue, [Microsoft.Extensions #2931](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2931#issuecomment-615493815), and [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995432/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-abstrac), I added to the project file the following.

```
<PropertyGroup> <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects> 
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType> </PropertyGroup>
```

I also followed an [article suggestion](https://azurelessons.com/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-abstractions/). After installing Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions, the error persists.

I also followed [another suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434453/azure-functions-host-error-has-occurred-during-startup-operation-could-not-load), and I added the following to my project file. However, the error persists.

```
<runtime> <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> <dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" 
publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" /> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.0.0.0" 
newVersion="5.0.0" /> </dependentAssembly> </assemblyBinding> </runtime>
```

I attempted the workaround suggested in issue [#401 of ASP.NET Core Announcements](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/401): reference the package for the assembly which is failing to load explicitly in my application. However, the error remains.

Using ILSpy, I found Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions, which I installed from NuGet, references Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version 2.1.0.0.

Answer (score 8):

`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0` - Looks like you are referring some parent nuget packages meant for **.net 5** which depends on this. At the time of this writing, Azure Function does not yet support **.net 5** (so quite possible see such issue from a forced v5 nuget reference as Function host works a bit differently than a regular asp.net core app) **UPDATE: Now supported**. Track [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6674) for future update. So, when needed, use only the 3.1.x latest version (not 5 yet) of any relevant nugets like `Microsoft.Extensions.*` or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*`.

N.B. Ideally you should not require any of those packages explicitly in Function though unless you need to do something special.

Comment: To run my Azure Function project locally, I resolved missing assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0 runtime error by referencing old versions of all its dependent DLLs and by including multiple old versions of this assembly. However, I received errors from GitHub Workflow CI/CD when attempting deployment to Azure: NU1605: Detected package downgrade
To deploy, I resolved by including in project file old versions of pkgs dependent on a common version of original missing assembly. https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/3694#issuecomment-733779020

Comment: Can you share your nuget reference list from csproj file?

Answer (score 0):

The related [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972495/azure-function-v3-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-dependenc), which links to issue [Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk #472](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/472) and finally to issue [Azure/azure-functions-host #6893.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6893#issuecomment-726386105) GitHub user, @AartBluestoke, summarized: "this can only be solved by upgrading azure functions to a newer version which has a dependency on the 5.x line of the abstractions."